# How to derive this equality involving kets and momentum?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

$p_{x} | \psi \rangle = \frac{\hbar}{i} \int dx' |x' \rangle \frac{\partial \langle x'| \psi \rangle}{\partial x'}$

$p_{x} = \frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$

I can't understand how does this equality hold:

$p_{x} | \psi \rangle = \int dx' p_{x} |x'\rangle \langle x'|  \psi \rangle= \frac{\hbar}{i}\int dx' \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} |x'\rangle \langle x'|  \psi \rangle $

Which is near, but not equal to the equality :/

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts gets you everything but the sign. The sign error seems to arise in the inconsistent definition and application of the momentum operator (the  $\hbar / i$ factor).

Quick edit:

It would be more precise to say that the momentum operator acts as a derivative in the position space basis which arises due to the matrix elements
$$\langle x \vert \hat{p}_{x} \vert x'\rangle = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x - x')$$
which could be introduced if we put another resolution of the identity to the left of the operator.